# How to make the bottom the beginning of an element?

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, alignment

I have a container that contains elements to be sorted using different sorting algorithms.

In one of these containers, the way I chose to make this sorting visible ends up causing two elements to be temporarily placed within the same div.

As a result, the size of the two elements is added together, making them larger than the container, causing the height of the container to grow as shown in the image.

[Element pushing the container content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySTiN.png)

The html is:

```css
.sort-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr));
  gap: 2px;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 20%;
  /* height: 200px; */
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


/* .sort-container div {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
} */

.sort-element {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #707070;
}
```

```html
<div data-sort="insertionSort" class="sort-container">
  <div>
    <div class="sort-element" style="height: ${altura}px">
    </div>
    <div class="sort-element" style="height: ${altura}px">
    </div>
    // All the other .stor-element
  </div>
</div>
```

My first idea was to use `overflow: hidden` and the result was that the elements kept being pushed downwards, but this time, the overflow was hiding the content on the negative y-axis, as shown in the image.

I believe this happens because, even though the items are aligned to the end of the flexbox, its start is still at the top.

That's why I want to know how to set the flexbox start as the end of the container.

[Conteiner with overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6OhT.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you want to do. I am assuming that you want to:

1. limit the height of the container
2. hide the overflow
3. have the visible content aligned from the bottom/end

If this is the case, then add `align-content: end` to `.sort-container` (and remove the wrapper `div`)

```css
.sort-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(1px, 1fr));
  gap: 2px;
  align-items: end;
  align-content: end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sort-element {
  background-color: #707070;
}


ol {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort-container" data-sort="insertionSort">
  <div class="sort-element">
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="sort-element">
    <ol>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```